# TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function ,Error in PHP autocomplete textbox

Tags: php, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('media'); ?>/autocomplete/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>media/js/order_new/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // alert("hii");
    $('#other').autocomplete({
      source: '<?php echo base_url('
      index.php ') ?>/frontend/location_autocomplete'
    });
  });
</script>



<input type="text" id="other" name="other" value="" placeholder="what your looking for?" class=" new_search" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source='[]'>
```

Comment: Please make sure all required javascript files are included with `<script>` tag.

Comment: Header is separate page and its included in all pages and that autocomplete is in header file and its working properly in home page of projects but not in inner pages.

Comment: Tidied the code. But please add description in your "question". Because currently, I'm not seeing "question marks"!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have not loaded jquery. Your application cannot find a reference to jquery($). Include jquery in your script resources before fetching jquery-ui into your application.

Answer (score 0):

Check the differences in your paths (`/`) and the libraries (jquery + jquery-ui):

```
<?php
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . base_url('media') . '/autocomplete/jquery-ui.css"/>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . base_url() . '/media/js/order_new/jquery.js"></script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . base_url() . '/media/js/order_new/jquery-ui.js"></script>';
?>
```

Check via your developer toolbar the existence of your paths.

Below an demo from `Autocomplete | jQuery UI` (https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                var availableTags = [
                    "ActionScript",
                    "AppleScript",
                    "Asp",
                    "BASIC",
                    "C",
                    "C++"
                ];
                $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                    source: availableTags
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
            <input id="tags">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: autocomplete is working properly in home page but not working in inner page its gives that TypeError

Comment: i added autocomplete textbox in header page that autocomplete is working properly in home page but when i go inside another page its not working in same header.

Comment: It sounds that every page starts with the <html> tag, so you need include the files there too.

Comment: Not every page start with <html> tag . Header is separate page and its included in all pages and that autocomplete is in header file and its working properly in home page of projects but not in inner pages.

Comment: Ok, possibly, you need to rebind the events?